# Interpreting access flags from hex value in java class file

Tags: java, class, parsing, hex

This is a hex dump of a java class file, the magic number, minor_version, major_version and constant pool have been excluded.

[image: Hex dump]

I want to find the access flags of the class. If I understand correctly, the access flag will be the first values in this hex dump, as the preceding values have been excluded.

This gives me the values 04 and 21 as access flags. My problem is that these don't correspond to the access flag values (there is no 21). How do I interpret these values to access flags from the below table?

```
ACC_PUBLIC  0x0001  Declared public; may be accessed from outside its package.
ACC_FINAL   0x0010  Declared final; no subclasses allowed.
ACC_SUPER   0x0020  Treat superclass methods specially when invoked by the invokespecial instruction.
ACC_INTERFACE   0x0200  Is an interface, not a class.
ACC_ABSTRACT    0x0400  Declared abstract; must not be instantiated.
ACC_SYNTHETIC   0x1000  Declared synthetic; not present in the source code.
ACC_ANNOTATION  0x2000  Declared as an annotation type.
ACC_ENUM    0x4000  Declared as an enum type.
```

Comment: Use `javap` to disassamble a `.class` file.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case I want to be able to interpret from the raw class file.

Comment: Why? `javap` does everything you need and it is probably more reliable than parsing hex dumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because all the **[Class access and property modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-E.1)** of specific attribute value(`True` or `False`) will attend the **[or operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)**  to build the whole flag. Let's say if a class is:

- Public `0x0001`
- Abstract `0x0400`

And the final flag will be

```
 0x0001|0x0400=0x0401
 # expand them to do the or operation:
                   Public
                   |
                   v
 0000 0000 0000 0001  <-- this is 0x0001
 OR
 0000 0100 0000 0000  <-- this is 0x0400
       ^
       |
      Abstract
 =
 0000 0100 0000 0001 <-- flag is 0x0401
```

So according to the flag (`0x0421`) of your class, the attribute should be:

- Abstract `0x0400`
- ACC_SUPER `0x0020`
- Public `0x0001`

Which will build a flag of `0x0421`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're confused by the fact that the access flags is a [*bitmask*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29). That is, the relevant flags are OR'ed together to get the bitmask. In the case of `0x0421` it is `ACC_ABSTRACT | ACC_SUPER | ACC_PUBLIC == 0x0400 | 0x0020 | 0x0001 == 0x0421`.

You can test if a flag, e.g. `ACC_ABSTRACT`, is set by AND'ing the flag constant with the bitmask. If it's non-zero then the flag is set. For example, `myFlags & ACC_ABSTRACT != 0`

You could also use Apache Common's [ClassParser](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/ClassParser.html). It already implements class file parsing for you.

Comment: @user2368481 I updated my answer. It seems you are confused with how bitmasks work. I didn't realize this until I reread your question.